# Oracle - Calculate max duration with multiple periods

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find a solution to the following problem:
Patients in the hospital stay in multiple departments (and rooms and beds) during their stay. They can be transferred internally and visit some departments twice or more.

So consider the following dataset:

| ID | BEGINNING | ENDING | DEPARTMENT | ROOM | BED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13-08-2021 10:42:00 | 15-08-2021 14:34:00 | HAEM | 123 | 456 |
| 2 | 13-08-2021 14:34:00 | 15-08-2021 09:22:00 | HAEM | 345 | 789 |
| 3 | 15-08-2021 09:22:00 | 28-08-2021 21:09:00 | ACH | 111 | 222 |
| 4 | 28-08-2021 21:09:00 | 01-09-2021 13:34:00 | HAEM |  |  |

I want to find the longest **uninterrupted** stay during their visit which is described as the **main department** of the case.

If I just take the MIN(BEGINNING) and MAX(ENDING) and group by the department the longest stay would be in the HAEM department (13-08 - 01-09) but in reality, the stay in the ACH department is the longest uninterrupted stay (15-08 - 28-08).

How can I accomplish that? I think I have to use LEAD to see when the department changes, but how can I set the partition then to find the MAX and MIN dates?

What I want to return is:

| DEPARTMENT | BEGINNING | END | DURATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| HAEM | 13-08-2021 10:42:00 | 15-08-2021 09:22:00 | 2 |
| ACH | 15-08-2021 09:22:00 | 28-08-2021 21:09:00 | 13 |
| HAEN | 28-08-2021 21:09:00 | 01-09-2021 13:34:00 | 4 |

Out of that, I can get the department I'm looking for.

[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=e65fc80ba2e9a2b458f5b5d6b567b0ed)

Comment: Questions... (1) Shouldn't your table also have a column for patient id? How do you know which row is for which patient? (2) If the time-of-day is not the same, how do you get a "duration" that is always an integer? For example, the first row value shouldn't be 2, but something like 1.9444. (3) Do you need the output you show, or do you need just the department of the maximum continuous stay? The output you show doesn't match your explanation in words. (4) What is your database version? Since Oracle 12.1, the best tool for this type of problem is `match_recognize`.

Comment: How come ACH started with ID = 3, but ended with ID = 2?

Comment: @mathguy (1) yeah it has one, but this is not relevant for the problem. (2) Yes, I just used ROUND, but it would be the same problem with decimal values :). (3) Both would be fine, for the patient I just need to have the department of the maximum continous stay. But with the solution proposed I can get there myself, as it is a nested query with OUTER APPLY anyway (4) Database Version is Oracle 21c. Thanks for the hint with MATCH_RECOGNIZE, will check it out.

Comment: @Max - what do you mean by "it's not relevant"? It is. If I write a query ignoring patient id and you use it on your table, you will find that it mixes things up between patients. If you run it by selecting the rows for one patient at a time, and then run my query, you will be wasting a lot of time. The query should work for all patients simultaneously.

Comment: Your sample data is also wrong - the second row overlaps with the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select
  grp,
  max(department) as department,
  min(beginning) as beginning,
  max(ending) as ending,
  max(ending) - min(beginning) as duration
from (
  select x.*,
    sum(inc) over(order by beginning) as grp
  from (
    select d.*,
      case when beginning = lag(ending) over(order by beginning)
            and department = lag(department) over(order by beginning)
        then 0 else 1 end as inc
    from case_departments d
  ) x
) y
group by grp
```

Result:

```
 GRP  DEPARTMENT  BEGINNING           ENDING              DURATION
 ---  ----------  ------------------  ------------------  ------------
 1    HAEM        13-AUG-21 10.42.00  15-AUG-21 14.34.00  +02 03:52:00
 2    ACH         15-AUG-21 09.22.00  28-AUG-21 21.09.00  +13 11:47:00
 3    HAEM        28-AUG-21 21.09.00  01-SEP-21 13.34.00  +03 16:25:00
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9c228ac9ca4f97c04eab5504d48529cc).

**Note**: I would assume there's a typo in the first row, and that the ending date of the first row is `13-08-2021 14:34:00`. Otherwise the query would need to account for overlapping.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `match_recognize` clause. The output shows all continuous stays in the same department (regardless of room and bed) for each patient. In the sample data I have just one patient, but the query should work without modification for all patients at once. If the output is needed for just one patient, that can be added as a filter (`where` clause).

I created slightly different data for testing - adding a column for patient id, and changing the `ending` for the first row so that there are no overlapping stays for the same patient (which make no sense in this use case).

Note that the choice of data type for `beginning` and `ending` is suboptimal; it should be changed to `date` if possible. As it is, I had to use `cast(... as date)` in the query. Without these casts, the result would be of `interval day to second` data type - which may be OK, but aggregation (such as taking the `max()`) is not supported for the interval data type, for reasons known only to Oracle.

**Data for testing:**

```
drop table case_departments purge;

create table case_departments(
  stay_id    number generated by default on null as identity,
  patient_id number,
  beginning  timestamp,
  ending     timestamp,
  department varchar2(50),
  room       varchar2(50),
  bed        varchar2(50)
);

insert into case_departments (patient_id , beginning, ending, department, room, bed) 
values (1239,
        to_date('13-08-2021 10:42:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
        to_date('13-08-2021 14:34:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
        'HAEM', 
        '123', 
        '456');
        
insert into case_departments (patient_id, beginning, ending, department, room, bed) 
values (1239,
        to_date('13-08-2021 14:34:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
        to_date('15-08-2021 09:22:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
        'HAEM', 
        '345', 
        '789');
         
insert into case_departments (patient_id, beginning, ending, department, room, bed) 
values (1239,
        to_date('15-08-2021 09:22:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
        to_date('28-08-2021 21:09:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
        'ACH', 
        '111', 
        '222');
        
insert into case_departments (patient_id, beginning, ending, department) 
values (1239,
        to_date('28-08-2021 21:09:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
        to_date('01-09-2021 13:34:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 
        'HAEM');

commit;
```

Which looks like this:

```
select * from case_departments;


STAY_ID PATIENT_ID BEGINNING               ENDING                  DEPARTMENT ROOM BED 
------- ---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ---------- ---- ----
      1       1329 2021-08-13 10:42:00.000 2021-08-15 14:34:00.000 HAEM       123  456 
      2       1239 2021-08-15 14:34:00.000 2021-08-16 09:22:00.000 HAEM       345  789 
      3       1239 2021-08-16 09:22:00.000 2021-08-28 21:09:00.000 ACH        111  222 
      4       1239 2021-08-28 21:09:00.000 2021-09-01 13:34:00.000 HAEM
```

**Query and output:**

```
select patient_id, department, beginning, ending,
       round(duration, 2) as duration
from   case_departments
match_recognize(
  partition by patient_id
  order     by beginning
  measures  f.department as department,  
            f.beginning  as beginning,
            last(ending) as ending,
            cast(last(ending) as date)
              - cast(first(beginning) as date) as duration
  pattern   ( f m* )
  define    m as department = f.department and beginning = prev(ending)
);

PATIENT_ID DEPARTMENT BEGINNING               ENDING                    DURATION
---------- ---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ----------
      1239 HAEM       2021-08-13 10:42:00.000 2021-08-15 09:22:00.000       1.94
      1239 ACH        2021-08-15 09:22:00.000 2021-08-28 21:09:00.000      13.49
      1239 HAEM       2021-08-28 21:09:00.000 2021-09-01 13:34:00.000       3.68
```

Comment: Great thanks a bunch!